# add function to functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

jQuery(function($){

```
$.ajax({
   url: adminAjax,
    type : "POST",
    data: {
        action: 'get_my_post',
        animal: 'animal',
        sport: 'sport',
        technologie: 'technologie',
        celebrity: 'celebrity'
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        $("#animalpost").html(data);
    }
})
```

this function return a query result from a function in functions.php when i add a condition :

if(is_page("test.php"))

the query ne returned nothing more please help me to fixe that

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_my_post', 'myfunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_my_post', 'myfunction' );  
function myfunction() {

    if ( isset( $_POST['animal'] ))
        {

         if(is_page( 'test' ) )

         {
           $args = array(   'post_type'   => 'journals'
    );   $journal = new WP_Query( $args );    if( $journal->have_posts() ):
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post an example of your code, so we can see what you've attempted and provide the best possible solution.

Comment: look above I add my source code

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: "<?php echo get_admin_url(); ?>admin-ajax.php",
    type : "POST",
    data: {
        action: 'get_my_post',
        animal: 'animal',
        sport: 'sport',
        technologie: 'technologie',
        celebrity: 'celebrity'
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        jQuery("#animalpost").html(data);
    }
})
```

Use this instead of your..hopefully it works :)